# Noun for a persons overall financial status

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am looking for a noun that encompasses the abstract idea of a persons overall financial status.

For example, a persons body (a noun that describes his/her physical presence) can have a disease that is causing it to be in poor health, while a persons **word I am looking for** can have toxic debt causing it to poor health.

Comment: Budget? Although a 'budget in poor health' doesn't make much sense, so you'll have to use some other descriptive.

Comment: The best I have been able to come up with is "Financial Wellness", but I was hoping for a single word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about it, we do, in fact speak of people’s or institutions’ finances as bein *in good health* or just *healthy*.  This metaphor is in common use.

I you are looking for a literal way of saying it, however, the most obvious (albeit somewhat ugly) word is *creditworthiness*.  the online Cambridge English dictionary gives the following definition.

> The state of being creditworthy (= having enough money for banks to be willing to lend money to you.)

You can find examples of its use here:  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/creditworthiness.

So If you have failed to repay debt, or are bankrupt your creditworthiness rating will be very low.  If, on the other hand you have high income and always make interest payments, your credit rating would be low.

The is a snag, of course.  If you never borrow and never use a credit card, you will have no credit rating at all.  That would be true whether you are a homeless person or a millionnaire who kept all your money in cash under your mattress.  Perhaps, though, that is no different from a person who never goes to the doctor.

Now credit ratings have not always worked as they should.  The ratings agencies went on rating banks at the top rating when we now know they were accelerating towards insolvency.  But doctors are not (or not supposed to be) fallible or corruptible in that way.

This might be a more elegant word for what you have in mind.

> Solvency

Answer (score 0):

It should be finance, I believe.
One of the definitions of finance is ‘monetary resources of an organisation or an individual’. The financial position or finances of a person may be in poor health, suggesting shortage of funds or burden of debts.

Comment: This would be improved with some expansion on why you believe this is the correct term in this case.

Comment: One of the definitions of finance is ‘monetary resources of an organisation or an individual’. The financial position or finances of a person may be in poor health, suggesting shortage of funds or burden of debts.

Comment: You should edit that into your answer as comments can be removed.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Financial condition covers both wealth, which includes indebtedness as well as assets, and income.